# Library for Validation in GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

I have an application developed using Pure GWT. Throughout the Application I need to do validation like email,phone number,SSN or Date validation.Is there any good third party JS or library available to integrate with GWT?

**note:Since I am getting the response in JSON throughout my application,I Can't Use GWT Validation Framework(GWTVF)

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html)?

Comment: yes i read that on also but its not matching to my application(since i m not using DTO object in UI side i m using JSON in response).

Comment: Well that would be crucial information to add to your question then.